# Drawing a circle made of lines and splitting into sections

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, information-graphics

I am looking to draw a circle like below on Illustrator for a graph. I get as far as doing the circular lines, but I just haven't been able to effectively split the circles in to equally sized sections. I've tried drawing lines over them and divide the objects with the Path tool, but it's dividing it weirdly. I think the problem is that the object below is not one object but rather a lot of circles. I've also considered using the scissors tool, but that will be hard to get the parts equal and the negative space divisions in the same size for all.

Is there a better way to do this? I very much appreciate the help and suggestions.

[image: example of circle]

Comment: Hello AJZ and welcome to GraphicDesign! Can you please include the attempt you have in the question itself so we can see what you mean by your description? Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

1. Make one arc by splitting it up
2. Make a second arc.
3. Make a blend between the 2 shapes.
4. Rotate copies.

Or

make full circles and eliminate lines in zones with shape builder.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually better if you follow [this tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAHNGSPNmks). It's way easier and cleaner. 
The video is not mine, but it was pretty short and easy to follow.

The steps are:

1. Draw a circle and a shape (in the video she uses a rectangle, but you can use all sorts of things).
2. Align vertically.
3. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> and select your object.
4. Select the rotate tool and click the center of the circle to fix your rotation point.
5. A dial box will pop up, select the degrees you want to rotate your object (in the video she recommends dividing 360° by the amount of shapes you want), then click "copy".
6. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (repeat operation) until satisfied.
7. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> again.
8. Bam.

(Still recomend watching the video though.)

Comment: Hi there Sophie and welcome to the GDSE. I took the liberty of cleaning up your formatting a little. The biggest improvement came from just adding a line break before the numbered list. I also "packed your link away", added keyboard keys and fixed a few typos.